# How to make CLion stop flagging PlatformIO dependencies with "file not found"?

Tags: clion, platformio, cmakelists-options

I'm experimenting with using PlatformIO and the CLion IDE. I'm pretty new to C++ and writing for embedded hardware. I got PlatformIO working and my simple program compiles and runs but CLion highlights my PlatformIO dependencies as not being found.

I've seen it said that CLion looks where cmake looks, but `CMakeLists.txt` says

```
# !!! WARNING !!! AUTO-GENERATED FILE, PLEASE DO NOT MODIFY IT AND USE
# https://docs.platformio.org/page/projectconf/section_env_build.html#build-flags
```

That URL seems like a dead end in terms of helping me solve my problem.

Answer (score 3):

Seems like the best way to do it is to go to Tools->PlatformIO->Re-Init. New dependencies should stop showing up as missing.

[image: Re-Init]

It worked for me.

Source: https://community.platformio.org/t/clion-cant-find-lib-deps-library-headers/23929/2

Answer (score 1):

***Update:***
I was playing a little bit more with CLion and PlatformIO and wanted to use the library manager as well.

The installed libraries are located in *{PROJECT_DIR}/.pio/libdeps/*

I was not able to detect all libraries automatically, but with the method described below, I could get rid of the CLion warninings by explicitly defining the dependencies in the *CMakeListsUser.txt* likes this

```
include_directories("${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/.pio/libdeps/mkrwifi1010/Keyboard/src")
include_directories("${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/.pio/libdeps/mkrwifi1010/WiFiNINA/src")
```

For the few dependencies I got, this is sufficient. But of course it is not ideal to add every dependency manually. So if somebody has a better solution, please share it.

***Original Answer***

I stumbled on a similar issue, but maybe this could help you or others.

In my case, I added the ArduinoLog library in the "lib" folder. Although I was able to compile my code, the import showed up as an error and I had no code completion.

As described in the XMakeList.txt, I was able to resolve this issue, by adding a "CMakeListsUser.txt" in the root project directory with the following content.

```
include_directories("${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/lib")
```

After a rebuild and a restart I got no more errors and the code completion worked as expected. Maybe you can add the folder of your PlatformIO libraries there as well.